# Python library "Crypto" conflict

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to integrate two frameworks, and I'm installing requirements for both of frameworks, but it seems like the library 'Crypto' used in both frameworks and have different versions of use, so if I install requirements for one of the frameworks, it returns me the first error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "dapp_bdb.py", line 134, in <module>
main()
File "dapp_bdb.py", line 112, in main
blockchain = LevelDBBlockchain(settings.chain_leveldb_path)
File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/neo/Implementations/Blockchains/LevelDB/LevelDBBlockchain.py", line 190, in __init__
self.Persist(Blockchain.GenesisBlock())
File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/neo/Implementations/Blockchains/LevelDB/LevelDBBlockchain.py", line 691, in Persist
account = accounts.GetAndChange(output.AddressBytes, AccountState(output.ScriptHash))
File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/neo/Core/TX/Transaction.py", line 121, in AddressBytes
return bytes(self.Address, encoding='utf-8')
File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/neo/Core/TX/Transaction.py", line 111, in Address
return Crypto.ToAddress(self.ScriptHash)
File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/neocore/Cryptography/Crypto.py", line 103, in ToAddress
return scripthash_to_address(script_hash.Data)
File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/neocore/Cryptography/Helper.py", line 78, in scripthash_to_address
return base58.b58encode(bytes(outb)).decode("utf-8")
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

and with the second requrirements of the  framework, it returns me other error:

```
exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 864, in run
self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "dapp_bdb.py", line 95, in custom_background_code
put_bdb("Hello world")
  File "dapp_bdb.py", line 68, in put_bdb
    fulfilled_creation_tx = bdb.transactions.fulfill(prepared_creation_tx, private_keys=private_key)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/bigchaindb_driver/driver.py", line 270, in fulfill
return fulfill_transaction(transaction, private_keys=private_keys)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/bigchaindb_driver/offchain.py", line 346, in fulfill_transaction
signed_transaction = transaction_obj.sign(private_keys)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/bigchaindb_driver/common/transaction.py", line 823, in sign
PrivateKey(private_key) for private_key in private_keys}
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/bigchaindb_driver/common/transaction.py", line 823, in <dictcomp>
PrivateKey(private_key) for private_key in private_keys}
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/bigchaindb_driver/common/transaction.py", line 817, in gen_public_key
public_key = private_key.get_verifying_key().encode()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-  packages/cryptoconditions/crypto.py", line 62, in get_verifying_key
return   Ed25519VerifyingKey(self.verify_key.encode(encoder=Base58Encoder))
 File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nacl/encoding.py", line 90, in encode
return encoder.encode(bytes(self))
 File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cryptoconditions/crypto.py", line 15, in encode
return base58.b58encode(data).encode()
AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

Is there any ideas how I can avoid it?

Comment: try virtualenvs, maybe?

Comment: the problem that this is one script, that needs to use both frameworks.

Comment: I dunno if this is a sane way or if it will work but maybe make separate virtualenvs and put the related code for each in there and import them to your main script?

Comment: Thanks, I'll consider this idea. However, I'm sure there should be another way.

Comment: Probably there is, I hope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like [cryptoconditions](https://github.com/bigchaindb/cryptocondition) library is doing it wrong.

You should file a bug asking to update required version of `base58` and review all the calls to it. Usual behavior for Python3 is to return `bytes` on `some_encoder_library.encode()` and `str` on `some_encoder_library.decode()`. New versions of `base58` module follow this rule although base58-encoded objects never contain any special symbols of course. `cryptoconditions` are still using previous version where `b58encode` were returning `str`.

Meanwhile you can make local modifications to the installed library or for it and install your fork instead. 
It is likely that everything will work OK with `encode()` call removed from [this line](https://github.com/bigchaindb/cryptoconditions/blob/a97fb94bed883a0b448e4e1ac75eede8951f088a/cryptoconditions/crypto.py#L15).